# Exercise 3-2 in K&R for C: convert escape sequences into visible ones

Tags: c, string, tabs, character, newline

K&R: Exercise 3-2. Write a function escape(s,t) that converts characters like newline and tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t as it copies the string t to s. Use a switch. Write a function for the other direction as well, converting escape sequences into the real characters.

Edit: Got it!! Thanks!! Do i need to add the s[s_index] = '\0'? It seems my program works fine without it (why though? shouldn't it cause an error or a memory problem)? ty again

My question: I'm not really sure if my algorithm is on the right path. Can someone please check my code below? It is not printing out any visible escape sequences. My idea was to replace each \n or \t scanned in from t, with a \ and then an n or a \ and then a t (using 2 spaces in the s array for every 1 space of t). Also, does anyone know how I would be able to assign a '\n' to a character array? For instance, if i typed in "hi" and then enter, it would scan in a \n into an array if i use c=getchar(). is there any other way for me to manually type in '\n' into an array before runtime? Thanks a lot guys! Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void escape(char s[], char t[]);

int main() {
    char s[50];
    char t[50] = "hello guys    bye test    bye\\n";
    escape(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

void escape(char s[], char t[]) {
    int s_index = 0;
    int t_index = 0;
    while (t[t_index] != '\0') {
        switch (t[t_index]) {
            case ('\n'):
                s[s_index] = '\\';
                s[s_index + 1] = 'n';
                t_index++;
                s_index = s_index + 2;
                break;
            case ('\t'):
                s[s_index] = '\\';
                s[s_index + 1] = 't';
                t_index++;
                s_index = s_index + 2;
                break;
            default:
                s[s_index] = t[t_index];
                s_index++;
                t_index++;
                break;
        }
    }
    s[s_index] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: it seems the function is correct . Only I would declare the second parameter with qialifier const.

Comment: try change `"hello guys    bye test    bye\\n"` to `"hello guys\tbye test\tbye\n"`

Comment: Edit: Got it!! Thanks!! Do i need to add the s[s_index] = '\0'? It seems my program works fine without it (why though? shouldn't it cause an error or a memory problem)? ty again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd be overly keen on learning C from K&R, it was a great book in its day but there are better ones around now, and the language has changed quite a bit.

But, at a bare minimum, you should move toward meaningful variable names and learn how to refactor common code so that you're not repeating yourself unnecessarily.

The code I would start with for this task would be along the following lines. It has common code centralised (as macros in this case, to simplify the code), and also prevents buffer overflows. First the requisite headers and helper macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Macros for output of character sequences,
//  including buffer overflow detection.

// Output a single character.

#define OUT_NORM(p1) \
    if (sz < 1) return -1; \
    sz--; \
    *to++ = p1;

// Output a backslash followed by a single
//  character.

#define OUT_CTRL(p1) \
    if (sz < 2) return -1; \
    sz -= 2; \
    *to++ = '\\'; \
    *to++ = p1;
```

Then the function itself, greatly simplified by the use of common code, and immune to buffer overflows:

```
static int escape (char *from, char *to, size_t sz) {
    // Process every character in source string.

    while (*from != '\0') {
        // Output control or normal character.

        switch (*from) {
            case '\n': OUT_CTRL ('n'); break;
            case '\t': OUT_CTRL ('t'); break;
            default:   OUT_NORM (*from);
        }
        from++;
    }

    // Finish off string.

    OUT_NORM ('\0');

    return 0;
}
```

And, finally, a test program for checking:

```
int main (void) {
    char src[] = "Today is a good\n\tday to die.\n";
    char dest[100];

    printf ("Original: [%s]\n", src);

    if (escape (src, dest, sizeof(dest)) != 0)
        puts ("Error found");
    else
        printf ("Final: [%s]\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```